# SharePoint 2010 - Export sites as template with the GUI -> ERROR

Tags: error, backup, export

I want to export a SharePoint site with the GUI.
I tried the two options, with and without content. But both ways are not working.
When I export a site, a correlation id is displayed.

What is the reason for this exception? It is possible to repair it?

In the log files are the following  entries:

> 08/02/2011 15:11:45.31 w3wp.exe (0x17FC)       0x2920  SharePoint Foundation                General               8e2s      Medium                Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x8000ffff      'GUID'
>
> 08/02/2011 15:11:45.31 w3wp.exe (0x17FC)       0x2920  SharePoint
>   Foundation                Fields    8tpt       Medium
>   Unable to locate the xml-definition for FieldName with FieldId
>   'GUID', exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic
>   failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetGlobalContentTypeXml(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 type, UInt32 lcid, Object varIdBytes)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetGlobalContentTypeXml(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 type, UInt32 lcid, Object varIdBytes)     --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetGlobalContentTypeXml(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 type, UInt32 lcid, Object varIdBytes)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.FetchFieldsFromWeb()
>   'GUID'
>
> 08/02/2011 15:11:45.32 w3wp.exe (0x17FC)       0x2920  SharePoint
>   Foundation                General               8e2s      Medium
>   Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x8000ffff
>   'GUID'

Comment: Is the export working 
a) on a different site within the same site collection?
b) on a different site collection within the same web app?
c) on a different wep app within the same farm?

Did you apply any customizations to your site?

Comment: a) We haven’t tried all sites but it appears, that all sites within the site collection are affected.
b) Other Site collection are not affected, but here again, we haven’t tried all site collections.
c) Same as b)
d) Customizations in place are in use in other site collections as well.